# Difference between the various forwarding options available

Tags: jsp, requestdispatcher

Can anyone out there let me know the differences between 
1) response.sendRedirect()
2) jsp:forward 
3) RequestDispatcher .forward 
4) RequestDispatcher .include 
 Different situations where they can be used specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) response.sendRedirect()**

*---when login of user failed due to wrong password you can redirect to  login page once again without any parameter or attributes*

response.sendRedirect sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the specified redirect location URL. This method can accept relative or absolute URL. Servlet container converts relative URL to absolute URL before sending response to client. If the location is relative without a leading '/' the container interprets it as relative to the current request URI. If the location is relative with a leading '/' the container interprets it as relative to the servlet container root.

**2)Difference between redirect and forward**

Servlet redirect and servlet forward both are used to handle the request processing to some other URL/Servlet but there is a big difference in the way it works. The main difference is
Servlet redirect always sends a HTTP status code 303 to client along with the redirect URL. Client then sends a new request to the URL.Thus response.sendRedirect() takes one more round trip than forward where as servlet forward just forwards the request to another resource on the server and it does not take a full round trip that is why forward is some time referred as server side redirect.
The another difference is you can redirect the request to some other URL on some another site but you can not forward the request to some other URL on different site.
Servlet forward will forward the existing request to another JSP or Servlet, so all the request parameters and attributes will be available to destination servlet. However with redirect, browser sends new request to specified URL, so old request parameters and attributes will not be available to destination resource.
Browser is completely unaware of servlet forward and hence the URL in browser address bar will remain unchanged. Where as the URL in browser address bar will change to new URL when servlet redirect is used.

**3) jsp:forward , jsp:include and
 RequestDispatcher .forward , RequestDispatcher .include are same**

*Jsp internally converted as Servlet ,So there is no different between Jsp Forward and Servlet Forward.*

when you want to forward your response and request RequestDispatcher .forward is useful

when you want to include some result RequestDispatcher .include is useful

Comment: Thanks for the insights provided.